# Does it induce a $\mathcal F^{\dagger}$-module $\mathcal M^{\dagger}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathcal F$ be a presheaf of rings on topological space $X$, and let $\mathcal M$ be a presheaf of $\mathcal F$-modules. Does it induce a $\mathcal F^{\dagger}$-module $\mathcal M^{\dagger}$?

Comment: Yes, just sheafify the map $\mathcal{F}\times\mathcal{M}\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Note that sheafification commutes with finite direct products, since they are the same as finite direct sums and those commute with sheafification since left adjoints commute with colimits.